# Iterating Django class object in manage.py shell?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to iterate through Django Class objects inside models.py in order to create a pie graph which is relevant to each Class object, based on information stored in another db.

Running the shell in the command prompt, I input:

```
from file.models import Person, piemaker
    for i in Person.objects.all():
    i.piegraph = i.pgraph()
    i.save()
```

When doing so, I get a piegraph as png file for each of the objects in my Person class; however, it looks like the graphs are being layed one on top of the other instead of popping out as a single graph. Like labels are repeated and on top of each other.

I am stuck at where this is broken, but my guess is inside my for loop? When I just run the piemaker function on one class object alone, it spits out the correct png file containing a nice piegraph.

```
from file.models import Person, piemaker
    a = Person.objects.get(name='name')
    a.piegraph = a.pgraph()
    a.save()
```

I have been working on this for two days straight to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!python3

###import statements####
from django.db import models
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##global start and end variables####
start = '2015-01-01'
end = '2016-01-01'

####fux for making, saving dynamic piegraph file
def piemaker(pietag):
        try:
 ####file to save as####
            filename = 'C:\\users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\Test2\\media_cdn\\pie-' + pietag + start + end+'.png'
        ####file name to return for Django FileField####
        file = 'pie-' + pietag + start + end+'.png'

        ###read my db which is external to Django to get parameters for pie graph
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE " + pietag + " = 1 AND post_date >= '" + str(start) + "' AND post_date <= '" + str(end) + "'", conn)
        df.drop(['sets'], axis=1, inplace=True)
        df = df.astype(int)
        df = df.loc[:, (df !=0).any(axis=0)]

        sums = df.sum()
        sums.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)
        other = 0
        for i in sums[3:]:
            other += i
            sums['other'] = other
        sums.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)
        pie = sums.drop(sums[4:].keys())
        plt.title('Texts/tags associated with ' + pietag + ' between: ' + start + '-' + end)
        plt.pie(pie,labels=pie.keys(), explode= (0,.15,0,0), startangle=90, autopct=make_autopct(pie))
        plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches='tight')
        return file
    except ValueError:
            return 'nothing here'

class Person(models.Model):


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def tag(self):
        return self.name.lower().replace(' ', '_')

    def pgraph(self):
        return(piemaker(self.tag))

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    tags = models.TextField(default='tag')
    piegraph = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that you are trying to use the interactive version of matplotlib. This will result in very strange results. Instead you need to use the Figure object and do something like the following:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def graphic(request):
        # other code goes here
        fig=Figure()
        fig1=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        fig1.pie((pie,labels=pie.keys(), explode= (0,.15,0,0), startangle=90, autopct=make_autopct(pie)))
        fig.savefig(filename)
        return filename
```

Comment: This was helpful as you pointed out correctly where the error was, i.e. that I was using an interactive plot. Nonetheless, I decided to solve this a bit differently, by simply adding one line to my function. The added line came after plt.savefig(...),  I added plt.clf() in order to clear the figure so a new one would be made on each iteration.

Comment: From my experience the use of the interactive version of matplotlib in django creates a lot of undesired results (server freeze etc.) as it is not supposed to be used in this case. So I would not recommend doing this.